# Win7 shows BSOD after rightclick

Tags: windows-7, bsod

My friend's Laptop shows a BSOD every time he right clicks, no matter where.

Any ideas?

He is using win7.

Comment: Does it also happen when using the [context menu key](http://www.lytebyte.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/right-click-keyboard-key.jpg) on your keyboard?
Also, does it happen with an external mouse? You can try to use a different one or the built in.
You can also try to switch left/right click in your mouse menu and see what happens when you left/right click.

Comment: it happens both with the internal and external mouse.

Comment: Just to get it out of the way, as I said before, check if switching Left with Right click in the Mouse Options makes the computer BSOD with Left Click. Also, the Context Menu is pretty much equivalent to the Right Mouse Button in standard setup, which is why I'm asking you to try

Comment: What's the STOP 0x number?  Can't really diagnose a BSOD without that.

Comment: If you can upload the latest crash minidump from the `%SystemRoot%\Minidump\ ` to somewhere, I can load it into WinDbg and have a dig around to see which module caused the fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He reinstalled Windows, so it's fixed now... :/

Comment: You might as well mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

[Use menumaid to disable](http://www.sdsoftware.org/software/menumaid/) all 3rd party context menu entries, see if the bsod stops, if it does, enable them one at a time until you find the one causing the issue.

If disabling all 3rd party entries does not help, then you know it is a core windows issue that needs to be debugged as suggested by Polynomial.

Comment: Just clicking in any program/window where no context menu has to be expected (or it cannot be modified by shell extensions) would be an easier way to diagnose.